# как из базы mysql поле text построчно обернуть в li?

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
<?php foreach ($posts as $post) : ?>


<strong>Обязанности:</strong>
<Ul>
<li><?= $post['Obyazannosti'] ?></li>
</Ul>

<strong>Требования:</strong>
<ul>
<li><?= $post['Requirements'] ?></li>
</ul>

<strong>Условия:</strong>

<ul>
<li><?= $post['Usloviya'] ?></li>
</ul>


<?php endforeach; ?>
```

в базе mysql поле Usloviya просто текст (это одно поле):

```
текст;
текст;
текст;
текст;
текст;
текст;
```

как сделать, чтобы при выводе из поля Usloviya  каждая строка оборачивалась в li?

Answer (score 1):

Для этого можно использовать функцию `explode()`, которая превращает строку в массив по разделителю. В вашем случае разделителем является `;`. Далее проходимся по массиву и выводим каждую строку.

```
<ul>
    <?php $uslovia = explode(';', $post['Uslovia']); ?>
    <?php foreach ($uslovia as $uslovie) : ?>
        <li><?= $uslovie ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

[Подробнее о функции `explode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)